App Stuck on ic_launcher Icon, Main Activity Not Launching - Android Studio
I'm not sure what's wrong with my app. When I launched it today from Android Studio on my physical device, it got stuck on the ic_launcher icon, and the main activity didn't load. I'm really confused because there are no errors, and I didn't make any code changes yesterday.
Here are the logs:
2024-09-22 13:28:29.041 14576-14576 AppCompatDelegate       com...dev91.hotornot_getyourratings  D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-09-22 13:28:29.192 14576-14576 DecorView               com...dev91.hotornot_getyourratings  I  setWindowBackground: isPopOver=false color=ff141218 d=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@d87aefd
...

Could anyone please help me figure this out? I'm also attaching a screenshot of the app for reference.

Also here is the manifest just incase
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/<ThemeName>"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


can you share the code of you main activity

Actually I made new project now as I have just started it , so currently that issue is resolved
